# magento admin prepare custom filter string for product grid

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, magento-enterprise

I am trying to add category filter in my admin product grid.
which i have added successfully but i am facing problem while pagination, for that i need to implement custom filter string for product grid, please provide some clue for preparing custom filter string. I have even tried below to set Default filter

```
$cat_ids = array(17,18);

$this->setDefaultFilter(array('category_id' => $cat_ids));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use default filter (or any filter for that mater) unless you have the columns referenced in the filter in your grid. So if the Grid does not contain the column category_id then it won't work.

You might want to add this filter in `_prepareCollection()`.

If your join needs a `group by` statement this will break the pagination, because ...well because that's how Magento works.

A workaround for this is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4088557/2047249). The post is about adding the category names to the product grid, but you can adapt it to work on `_prepareCollection()`.

The main idea is to change the `getSelectCountSql()` method that is used for calculating the pagination to behave differently when you have a group by.